# Compiler can't find the class JpegBitmapEncoder in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i'm losing it,
what am i doing wrong ?

`Error  3   The name 'BitmapFrame' does not exist in the current context`

`Error  2   The type or namespace name 'JpegBitmapEncoder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Code:**

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.CRUDSqlAzure.Phone.Converters
{
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] rawImageBytes = (byte[])value;
        BitmapImage imageSource = null;

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rawImageBytes))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
                b.SetSource(stream);
                imageSource = b;
            }
            return imageSource;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }


    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = (BitmapImage)value;
            byte[] data;
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(ms);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return data;

        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight on wp7 doesn't have JpegBitmapEncoder. If you want to convert a BitmapSource to a byte array you can do that using the WriteableBitmap's SaveJpeg method:

```
try
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = (BitmapImage)value;
    byte[] data;
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, bitmapImage.PixelWidth, 0, 100);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return data;
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

If you want to convert the BitmapSource to other file format like png or gif you have to use third party libraries like [.NET image tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/).

But it's not a good idea to convert images back and forth in a converter. I don't even think you really need to. What control do you use which modifies the BitmapSource? :\

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to bind it to an `<image>`  element on my xaml page. I need to use a converter for this as i save the data in a byte[]

Comment: I still don't understand completely what you're trying to do. So you have your image saved as a byte array... Well everything is stored as an array of bytes, so that's okay. You want to bind that to an Image control. Ok, you have to use a converter to convert the byte array to an ImageSource. But why do you need to convert it back?

Comment: good point actually, thinking about it, when i read from the database to the app i need to convert from byte array to imagesource, when i take a photo with the phone's camera and save to the db i need to convert it from imagesource to byte array.

Comment: I think it's a better idea to save the camera photo on an event, IMHO this is not a problem which you want to solve with binding.

Comment: you are probably right, i'm new to this and still finding out how to update the model data context in my MVVM app with the new picture i took. a bit confusing

Comment: MVVM can complicate and confuse some things. It's a completely correct solution if you subscribe for events in you view code, and update the viewmodel's property manually or call a method on the viewmodel. A lot of people try to solve everything with bindings and without writing any code in the view.